# How can I create an shared context between OpenGL and OpenCL with glfw3 on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, interop, opencl

I am building a particle system using OpenGL and OpenCL. I need to share VBOs between OpenGL and OpenCL and therefore create an OpenCL context with the appropriate properties.

I am aware that glfw3 exposes some native API functions however I can't figure out how to access the CGL ones.

https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h

I basically need to find how to run this with glfw3:

```
CGLContextObj kCGLContext = CGLGetCurrentContext();
CGLShareGroupObj kCGLShareGroup = CGLGetShareGroup(kCGLContext);

cl_context_properties properties[] =
{
    CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE,
    (cl_context_properties)kCGLShareGroup,
    0
};
```

The problem is also [discussed on the glfw github](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/104) but doesn't answer the question for OSX.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [`opengl_create_shared_context()`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost_compute/reference.html#header.boost.compute.interop.opengl.context_hpp) function provided by the [Boost.Compute](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/program.html) library. This function takes care of handling the platform-specific issues involved when creating a shared OpenCL-OpenGL context.

Comment: Newer link: https://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/opengl_create__idp51936400.html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `glfw3native.h` is here: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/glfw3native_8h.html

I'm not familiar with OSX, but I'm assuming you'll want to use `glfwGetNSGLContext` to get the GL context. I believe you can still use `CGLGetCurrentContext` even if you are using GLFW, and it appears you'll still have to use `CGLGetShareGroup` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [my answer to a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609454/how-to-create-opencl-context-based-on-the-opengl-context-on-mac-os-x/38460413#38460413).

In fact you don't need `glfw3`'s methods to access the current OpenGL context. Just `#include` the following header files and you should be good to go with your example code.

```
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
```